# NewPooledConnection leaks

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, c3p0

I'm using MySQL with Spring, Hibernate and c3p0 connection pool.
And here is the configurations xml.

```
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="30" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="120" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="60" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="90" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="10" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="10000" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1;" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="2000" />
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="10" />
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="10" />
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" />
```

This is how I doing CRUD.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactoryLocal")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public synchronized Session getCurrentSession() {
    return this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public void insert(Object obj) {
    Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(obj);
}

@Override
public void delete(Object obj) {
    Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(obj);
}

@Override
public void insertOrUpdate(Object obj) {
    Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
}

@Override
public void update(Object obj) {
    Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(obj);
}
```

I have every service with the @Transactional annotation.
So the Spring should handle when to open and close session. 
The problem is the open files keeps increasing on my Linux server.
Then I found the connection is not leaking, but the Object itself not released from `Map`.
Because the query never failed. It just uses all the memory on my server and slows down every request.
There are thousands of these objects over there and keeps increasing on every query.

[image]

But it prints the connection was destroyed successfully from c3p0.

```
2019-07-30 01:25:41 [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool]-[DEBUG] Preparing to destroy PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4d5610a0
2019-07-30 01:25:41 [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool]-[DEBUG] Successfully destroyed PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4d5610a0
```

The `sessionFactory` is singleton. So there must be only one connection pool.
The max connection size is 200.
How come there are thousands of NewPooledConnection in the pool?
What's the problem?

**UPDATE 1**

```
@Repository("crudLocal")
public class CRUD extends SecureBaseDao implements IBaseDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactoryLocal")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

}

@Repository
public class HotTopicDao implements IHotTopicDao {

    private static final Class<HotTopic> ENTITY_CLASS = HotTopic.class;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("crudLocal")
    private IBaseDao crud;
}

@Service
@Transactional("transactionManagerLocal")
public class HotTopicService implements IHotTopicService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HotTopicService.class);

    @Autowired
    private IHotTopicDao hotTopicDao;
}

@Controller("v1.hotTopicsController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/hotTopic")
public class HotTopicsController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HotTopicsController.class);

    @Autowired
    private FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("configuration")
    private Configuration configuration;

    @Autowired
    private IHotTopicService hotTopicService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public String get(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp,
                       @Valid @RequestBody List<String> params,
                       BindingResult bindingResult){
        return getHandler(req, resp, params, bindingResult, false);
    }

}
```

And this is how I build statement.

```
@Override
public <T> Query findByHql(String filter, Map<String, Object> params, 
    String fields, String orderBy, String groupBy, Class<T> entityClass) {
    Session session = this.getCurrentSession();

    String entityName = entityClass.getSimpleName();
    StringBuffer statementBuff = new StringBuffer();

    if( fields != null ){
        statementBuff.append(" SELECT " + fields);
    }

    statementBuff.append(" FROM " + entityName);
    statementBuff.append(" " + entityName.toLowerCase());

    if( filter != null ){
        statementBuff.append(" WHERE " + filter);
    }
    if( groupBy != null ){
        statementBuff.append(" GROUP BY " + groupBy);
    }
    if( orderBy != null ){
        statementBuff.append(" ORDER BY " + orderBy);
    }

    String statement = statementBuff.toString();

    Query query = session.createQuery(statement);

    if( params != null ){
        Set<String> keySet = params.keySet();
        for( String key : keySet ){
            query.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
        }
    }

    return query;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found that it may not be a leaking problem after I tested it on the official Tomcat container of Docker. Just my server is too busy so it's not able to release resources.
I tried to use JMeter and made 40000 requests in 20 seconds, the opened files raised up to 1000. But it dropped down to 108 after a while without any request.

Comment: You don't need to synchronize this method I think `public synchronized Session getCurrentSession()`, also, try to post a complete sample class with annotations. Check for possible [anti-patterns session-per-user-session or session-per-application](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions.html).